# HTTParty with Digest Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I would like to connect to an API using Ruby On Rails 2.3.8 and HTTParty gem.

My model is the following:

```
class Onnion < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'net/http'
  include HTTParty

  base_uri 'http://myapiurl.com'
  digest_auth 'user', 'password'
  disable_rails_query_string_format

  def self.create_rma(order)

    put('/orders/rma', :query => {:action => 'put', :data => {:api_key => 'user', :onnion_order_id => order.id, :customer_rma => order.saving.profile.user.id, :comments => ''}})
  end
end
```

What I would like to do is to call a method of the API called Put, with certain parameters grouped within `data` parameter.

After executing this method I'm getting a `401 Unauthorized` error message.

What am I doing wrong? This is the first time I'm trying to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

What version of HTTParty are you using, and have you tried using the very latest version from Github? There were some fixes to do with digest auth security a little while ago in version `0.7.3`.

If that doesn't work it could be that the server you're attempting to talk to isn't following protocol correctly. I've had this happen before, had to monkey patch HTTParty to get it to login correctly. I'll put the patch I used here in-case it works for you...

```
module Net
  module HTTPHeader
    class DigestAuthenticator
      # use NC = 1 instead of 0
      def authorization_header
        @cnonce = md5(random)
        header = [%Q(Digest username="#{@username}"),
          %Q(realm="#{@response['realm']}"),
          %Q(nonce="#{@response['nonce']}"),
          %Q(uri="#{@path}"),
          %Q(response="#{request_digest}")]
        [%Q(cnonce="#{@cnonce}"),
          %Q(opaque="#{@response['opaque']}"),
          %Q(qop="#{@response['qop']}"),
          %Q(nc="1")].each { |field| header << field } if qop_present?
        header
      end

    private
      def request_digest
        a = [md5(a1), @response['nonce'], md5(a2)]
        a.insert(2, "1", @cnonce, @response['qop']) if qop_present?
        md5(a.join(":"))
      end
    end
  end
end

module HTTParty
  class Request
    def setup_digest_auth
      # issue a get instead of a head request
      res = http.get(uri.request_uri, options[:headers]||{})
      if res['www-authenticate'] != nil && res['www-authenticate'].length > 0
        @raw_request.digest_auth(username, password, res)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The changes made were to send NC 1 and not NC 0, and also to do a GET request, rather than a HEAD request in `setup_digest_auth`

Comment: I'm using version 0.7.8. So I think this should be fixed already.